# Why is the link_to submitting form twice?

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I am trying to use JavaScript with jquery in rails to update a div without reloading the page. Its working but the comment is being created twice. I know something is wrong in the form partial but couldn't figure it out. Any help?

The following are the files -

## _new_comment.html.erb

```
<%= form_for [:home, Comment.new], :url => home_comments_path, :html => {:id => "comment-new-" + post.id.to_s} do |f| %>

    <div>
        <%= f.text_area :message, :class => "message-area-" + post.id.to_s, :placeholder => "Add comment..." %>

        <%= f.hidden_field :post_id, :value => post.id %>

        <span class="new-comment"><%= link_to 'Add', '#', remote: true, :onclick => "$('#comment-new-#{post.id}').submit()" %></span>
    </div>

<% end %>
```

## comments_controller.rb

```
def create
    @comment = Comment.new(comment_params)
    @comment.user_id = current_user.id

    if @comment.save
        flash[:notice] = 'Comment added sucessfully'
        respond_to do |format|
            format.html { redirect_to home_posts_url }
            format.js
        end
    end
end
```

## create.js.erb

```
$("#comment-new-83").before('<div class="notice"><%= escape_javascript(flash[:notice]) %></div>');
$("#comment-new-83")[0].reset();
```

## home.js

```
jQuery.ajaxSetup({
    'beforeSend': function(xhr) {xhr.setRequestHeader("Accept", "text/javascript")} 
})

$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#comment-new-83").submit(function() {
        $.post($(this).attr("action"), $(this).serialize(), null, "script");
        return false;
    })
})
```

Comment: Remove `remote: true` from `link_to` and try and also `:onclick`.

Comment: where would i use onclick?

Comment: You don't need to put `:onclick` anywhere because you are already binding `submit` event to the form.

Comment: You can narrow down the problem by checking if two requests are sent to the server on click. If so the problem is in the frontend, otherwise, the backend.

Comment: also try `event.preventDefault` instead of `return false;`

Comment: still not solved. Any other suggestions? @Kris

Comment: Check that JQuery is not being loaded twice. Some gems (e.g. ActiveAdmin) load their own copy of JQuery, which means you can get two copies of JQuery loaded. This can cause duplication on the page. Have a look at the HTML head in the page source to see if jquery is loaded twice there.

Comment: in `create.js.erb`  try change the line orders.

Comment: No. Jquery is not loaded twice and create.js.erb is giving the same result.

Comment: did you figure out if the issue is the front or backend...

Comment: for trial purpose i only took one post - post no. 83. Its working fine with other divisions. I think that means there is a problem in the backend

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`form_for` will automatically post to the controller. You need not submit the form explicitly using jquery.

[Reference](http://guides.rubyonrails.org/form_helpers.html#binding-a-form-to-an-object)

Comment: Yup. Solved. Added remote: true in the form_for statement and it's done. Thankyou